# in my java script code xhr.status shows zero

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

why i get Zero from alert(xhr.status);  ?

i set break point . on my controller . first, it shows  0 and then go on my controller. shows username null there.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btn').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                //url: 'Home/MyAction',
                //data: { username: 'Jack' },
                //cache: false,
                //type: 'POST',
                //error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                    //alert(xhr.status);
                    //alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
                //},
                //successs: function (data) { alert('successs'); }

               var url = '@Url.Action("Save", "Home")';
            $.post(url, {
                username: 'jack'
            }, function (data) {
                if (data)
                    alert("ok");
                else
                    alert("error");

            });


            });

        });


        //return false;
    });
```

my controller is like below :

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MyAction(string username)
    {

        try
        {

            var data = new
            {
                sent = true
            };
            return Json(data);

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            var data = new
            {
                sent = false,
                errorMessage = e.Message

            };

            return Json(data);
        }

    }
```

it may depend on my controller ?

Comment: Can you post your controller's code?

Comment: Try adding dataType:'json' and see if it helps.

Comment: no , it did not change

Comment: *"it shows 0 and then **go on my controller**"* your `return false` is in the wrong place, fixing that will make it stop going to your controller. Now you just need to fix the controller or the ajax options.

Comment: no , it's not because of it . i do'nt know what's my mistake

Comment: i changed ajax . now  , it dose not show 0 . but send username null to controller . i'm updating my question to new ajax code

Answer (score 0):

Change `successs: function (data) { alert('successs'); }`

to

```
success: function (data) { alert('success'); }
```

spelling error in `success`

the edited code is

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#btn').click(function () {

            $.ajax({
                url: 'Home/MyAction',
                data: { username: 'Jack' },
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, error) {
                    alert(xhr.status);
                    alert('Error: ' + xhr.responseText);
                },
                success: function (data) { alert('success'); }


            });

        });


        return false;
    });
```